# Understanding an acceleration of a ramp

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, acceleration

What acceleration should be preformed on a ramp itself, so that it seems like the object on it is falling vertically downwards? We should probably apply high force, so that its acceleration increases. I'm interested in how to measure the acceleration needed so that body is constantly falling vertically downwards.

Comment: I'm very confused by this question.  A body doesn't need to accelerate to fall vertically downwards.  This is very unclear.

Comment: No, I meant what force (0r the acceleration the ramp should have) we should apply on the ramp (in a diferrent direction), so that it looks like the body (which is on the ramp and not moving) falls vertically downwards. I assume it should be a great force, but how to measure it using equations. It would probably be easier if you're given a sketch of the situation.

Comment: That situation has a lot of factors.  Especially when it comes to the ramp geometry and mass.  It would probably be beneficial for you to draw it out and try to determine some of this for yourself as well.

Comment: Ok. If an object on the ramp has a greater mass, then I suppose we should apply greater force too. Or it depends only on the mass of the ramp?

Comment: It depends on a lot of things, and "greater force" is an extremely vague statement.

Comment: I think the question is already clear. He wants to know the needed force to make the vertical component of the acceleration to $g$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the object to be in free fall with acceleration $g$, the point on the ramp directly below the object has to accelerate downwards at the same rate $g$.

[image]

Suppose the ramp is inclined at angle $\theta$ to the horizontal, sloping down to the left. If the ramp moves to the right a distance $x$ then the point below the object moves down by a distance $y=x\tan\theta$. If the ramp accelerates to the right at rate $\ddot x$ then the point below the object will accelerate down at rate $\ddot y = \ddot x \tan\theta$. In order to make $\ddot y=g$ so that the object is in free fall, the acceleration of the ramp must be
$$\ddot x =\frac{g}{\tan\theta}=g\cot\theta$$

When the ramp is vertical $(\theta=90^{\circ}, \ddot x=0)$ it does not need to move. When the ramp is horizontal $(\theta=0^{\circ}, \ddot x=\infty)$ it cannot move fast enough to get out of the way.

The acceleration $\ddot x$ of the ramp is constant, because $g, \theta$ are constants. The constant force on the ramp is $F=M\ddot x$ where $M$ is the mass of the ramp. (I assume the ramp slides on a frictionless plane surface.)

There is no force between the object and the ramp. Any such force would slow the descent of the object, then it would not be in free fall. The ramp moves so that it just avoids being hit by the object as the object falls freely.

Comment: neglecting friction, presumably?

Comment: I think that is implied. If the body is in free fall then the normal reaction will be zero, hence friction will be zero.

Comment: @sammygerbil There can still be acceleration between the ramp and the surface it's sliding on (it's also very trivial relative to the meat of the problem, so I don't disagree with not including it).  That would only be for calculating the force of the ramp anyways, which you seem to have left for the asker.

Answer (score 0):

Acceleration of the ramp should be $g/tan(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the wedge angle. To get force, multiply that by ramp mass $m$. (That's ignoring friction.)

[image]